# What is the following expression equal to?

Tags: calculus, special-functions

What is the following expression equal to?
$$z^{\alpha } \left(\, _2F_1\left(1,-\alpha ;1-\alpha ;\frac{1}{z}\right)+\, _2F_1(1,\alpha ;\alpha +1;z)-1\right)$$
The derivative of it with respect to z is zero. And the limit of it when z goes to zero is $$\pi  \alpha  (\cot (\pi  \alpha )+i)$$, while the limit of it when z goes to 1 is 
 $$\pi  \alpha  (\cot (\pi  \alpha )-i)$$.

Comment: According to Mathematica, there is a minus sign difference in between real and imaginary parts of both lhs and rhs expressions...can you confirm?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo. I have the feeling that is works as it is (done numerically).

Comment: For $z=8.2$ and $a=2.2$, my Mathematica gives for the lhs 9.51287 - 6.9115 I and for the rhs 9.51287 + 6.9115 I...

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo You are right. But I series expanded it around z=0, the equation is correct.

Comment: @HChan. I am not sure I understand. How can I be right (which implies that there exists at least one pair of values $(z,\alpha)$ for which the identity is not true), and simultaneosuly be the equation "correct"?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo I think the reason is that the equation is not valid in the whole complex plane, and it may also depend on Arg[z]. In your case, -6.9115-6.9115=-2Pi a I.

Comment: Ok. the derivative w.r.t. $z$ of the l.h.s. is indeed identically zero. Therefore it should be sufficient to compute the l.h.s. in a suitable value of $z$ (like $\lim_{z\to 1}$) to establish the identity...

Comment: which gives -1 - I a \[Pi] + a PolyGamma[0, -a] - a PolyGamma[0, a]..

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo That's Pi a(-i+cot(Pi a)). I think my question now is that since the derivative of the l.h.s. is zero, what is the l.h.s. equal to?

Comment: I'm confused. If its derivative is equal to $0$ and you know the limit, what's stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. It only cover the case where $\alpha \ne 0$ and $0 \le \Re\alpha < 1$.

For any $\beta \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$, let $G_\beta(z)$ be the shorthand for ${}_2F_1(1,\beta;\beta+1;z)$. The equality at hand can be rewritten
as
$$z^\alpha \left( G_{-\alpha}(1/z) + G_{\alpha}(z) - 1 \right) \stackrel{?}{=} \pi\alpha(\cot(\alpha) + i)\tag{*1}$$

For any nonzero $\beta$ with $|\Re\beta| < 1$ and $|z| < 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}G_\beta(z) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_k (\beta)_k}{k!(\beta+1)_k} z^k
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\beta}{\beta+k} z^k =
1 + \beta\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \int_0^1 t^{\beta+k-1} dt \right) z^k\\
&= 1 + \beta \int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty (tz)^k \right) dt
= 1 + \beta z \int_0^1 \frac{t^{\beta}}{1 - tz} dt
\end{align}\tag{*2}
$$
Please note that the integral in RHS$(*2)$ is well defined for any $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus [1,\infty)$. Let $C$ be any closed contour in $\mathbb{C}\setminus [1,\infty)$ and consider following double integral:

$$\int_C \left( \int_0^1 \frac{t^\beta}{1-tz} dt \right) dz$$

Since $[0,1] \times C$ is compact and $1 - tz \ne 0$ for any $(t,z) \in [0,1] \times \mathbb{C}\setminus [1,\infty)$, the term $\displaystyle\;\left|\frac{1}{1-tz}\right|\;$ in the integrand is bounded from above over $[0,1] \times C$. As long as $|\Re\beta| < 1$, the double integral is absolutely integrable and we can exchange the order of integration. Together with Cauchy integral theorem, we find:

$$\int_C \left( \int_0^1 \frac{t^\beta}{1-tz} dt \right) dz
= \int_0^1 \left( \int_C \frac{t^\beta}{1-tz} dz \right) dt
= 0
$$
Since $C$ is arbitrary, by Morera's theorem, the integral
$\int_0^1 \frac{t^\beta}{1-tz} dt$
defines an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [1,\infty)$. We can use
$(*1)$ to analytic continue $G_\beta(z)$ over $\mathbb{C}\setminus [1,\infty)$.

From now on, assume $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$.

Let $\alpha \ne 0$ be any number in the strip $0 \le \Re\alpha < 1$.

Substitute $\beta$ by $\alpha$ in $(*2)$, we have

$$G_\alpha(z) = 1 + \alpha \int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-tz} -1\right) dt = \alpha \int_0^1 \frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1-tz}dt\tag{*3a}$$

Substitute $\beta$ by $-\alpha$ in $(*2)$ and change variable to $s = 1/t$, we find

$$G_{-\alpha}(1/z) = 1 - \frac{\alpha}{z}\int_1^\infty \frac{s^\alpha}{1 - \frac{1}{zs}} \frac{ds}{s^2}
= 1 + \alpha \int_1^\infty \frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{1 - zs}ds\tag{*3b}
$$
Combine $(*3a)$ and $(*3b)$, we have

$$z^\alpha \left(G_{-\alpha}(1/z) + G_{\alpha}(z) - 1\right)
= \alpha z^\alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1-zt} ds\tag{*4}$$
To evaluate the integral on $(*4)$, consider following contour $C_\epsilon$

$$+\infty - \epsilon i\quad\to\quad  -\epsilon - \epsilon i \quad\to\quad -\epsilon + \epsilon i \quad\to\quad +\infty + \epsilon i$$

If we choose the branch cut of $s^{\alpha-1}$ along the positive real axis and
pick the branch where argument of $t^{\alpha-1}$ is $0$ on the upper side of the cut. We have

$$(1 - e^{2\pi\alpha i})\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1-tz} dt =
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{C_\epsilon} \frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1-tz} dt$$
When $\Re\alpha < 1$, the integrand fall off fast enough as $|t| \to \infty$. We can complete the contour $C_\epsilon$ by a circle at infinity and convert the contour integral over $C_\epsilon$ to evaluation of residues within the extended contour. We obtain

$$\alpha z^\alpha  \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1-tz}dt
= 2\pi i\left(\frac{\alpha z^\alpha}{1 - e^{2\pi\alpha i}}\right)\mathop{\text{Res}}_{t = 1/z}\left(\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1-tz}\right)
= \frac{2\pi i\alpha}{e^{2\pi\alpha i} - 1} z^{\alpha-1} \left[ t^{\alpha-1} \right]_{t=1/z}$$

Since we are taking the branch cut for $t^{\alpha-1}$ along the positive real axis. When $z = re^{i\theta}$, the correct value of $1/z$ to put into
$\left[ t^{\alpha-1} \right]_{t=1/z}$ should be $r^{-1} e^{(2\pi - \theta)i}$.
This leads to

$$z^{\alpha-1} \left[ t^{\alpha-1} \right]_{t=1/z} = (re^{i\theta})^{\alpha-1} (r^{-1}e^{(2\pi - \theta)i})^{\alpha-1} = e^{2\pi\alpha i}$$
As a result,

$$\text{RHS}(*4) = 2\pi i\alpha \frac{e^{2\pi\alpha i}}{e^{2\pi\alpha i} - 1}
= \pi \alpha i  \left( \frac{e^{2\pi \alpha i} + 1}{e^{2\pi \alpha i} - 1} + 1\right)
= \pi \alpha (\cot(\pi\alpha) + i )
$$

This justify $(*1)$ when

- $\alpha\ne 0$, falls inside the strip $0 \le \Re\alpha < 1$,
- $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$,
- the branch cut of $z^{\alpha}$ is taking along the +ve real axis,
- $\arg z = 0$ on upper side of +ve real axis.

Comment: The way I like to prove that particular identity is by splitting $(0,\infty)$ into $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty),$ then letting $x=\dfrac1t$ on the latter, and rewriting the integral as a difference of two [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) using $x^a-x^b=(1-x^b)-(1-x^a),$ then appealing to the relation between the latter and [digamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers), and lastly employing Euler's famous [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).